# Count items get from php in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner web developer.

My code retrieves data from php and dynamically displays it on the page.
This code get data from php.

I have this code:

```
let productCount = 0;
    function loadProducts() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/pobierz-produkt',
                dataType: "text",
                data: {
                    slug: slug,
                    queryString: queryString,
                    filterDrawer: $(".filter-drawer option:selected").val(),
                    filterMounting: $(".filter-mounting option:selected").val(),
                    filtershelfs: $(".filter-shelfs option:selected").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.dynamic-products').html(data);
                    let productCount = 5;
                    if (productCount == 1) $('.dynamic-products-count').html('5 produktów');
                    if (productCount >= 2 && productCount <= 5) $('.dynamic-products-count').html(productCount + ' produkty');
                    else $('.dynamic-products-count').html(productCount + ' produktów');
                }
            });
        }
```

It's work fine.

This code return me:

```
<div class="product-card">
        <div class="mt-5 w-100">
            <div class="w-100 mb-3 product-card-img-box text-center text-md-left">
                <a href="http://name.test/produkt/produkt-1">
                                            <img src="http://name.test/upload/products/thumbs3/559c3b396bca9c33e6dcc32ad36bc732.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
                                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-card-name-box text-center text-md-left">
                <a class="product-card-new-info" href="#">Nowość</a><br/>
                <div class="product-card-name pt-3">
                    <a href="http://name.test/produkt/produkt-1">Produkt 1 tv blue</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-card-category text-center text-md-left"><a
                    href="http://name.test/produkt/produkt-1">mini opis</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-card">
        <div class="mt-5 w-100">
            <div class="w-100 mb-3 product-card-img-box text-center text-md-left">
                <a href="http://name.test/produkt/produkt-2">
                                            <img src="http://name.test/upload/products/thumbs3/38ae98e033d9c2dddc7b2ca7fff9acd4.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
                                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-card-name-box text-center text-md-left">
                <a class="product-card-new-info" href="#">Nowość</a><br/>
                <div class="product-card-name pt-3">
                    <a href="http://name.test/produkt/produkt-2">Produkt 2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-card-category text-center text-md-left"><a
                    href="http://name.test/produkt/produkt-2"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-card">
        <div class="mt-5 w-100">
            <div class="w-100 mb-3 product-card-img-box text-center text-md-left">
                <a href="http://name.test/produkt/szafka-z-szufladami">
                                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-card-name-box text-center text-md-left">
                <a class="product-card-new-info" href="#">Nowość</a><br/>
                <div class="product-card-name pt-3">
                    <a href="http://name.test/produkt/szafka-z-szufladami">Szafka z szufladami</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-card-category text-center text-md-left"><a
                    href="http://name.test/produkt/szafka-z-szufladami"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need save to productCount how many "product-card" was returned from php.

How can I make it? I need count "product-card"

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is pure HTML returned, you can use :

```
success: function (data) {
    // create fake div
    var $data = $('<div />').html(data);

    var count = $data.find('.product-card').length;
}
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hfwuznvd/

Answer (score 0):

You can count the length of JSON objects using **Object.keys(myObject).length;**

```
  var myObject = {'name':'Kasun', 'address':'columbo','age': '29'}
  var count = Object.keys(myObject).length;
  console.log(count);
```